# Nodejs bin code was changed to src code, how to get it back?

Tags: node.js, html, socket.io

i was working on code for my online game, and (my mistake), i was editing the game script in the bin folder. Now i turned off the server and then back on, and now the bin code was replaced with the src code! I'm using a mac, how can i get my 2 months of hard work back?

I'm using nodejs and socket.io

Comment: What is `bin` code?  Are you running at transpiler?

Comment: It's called use a version control system next time.